# Bash script using curl to hit urls provided by txt file

Tags: bash, curl

What I want is a script with curl to hit some special links I have in txt file. Only to hit the urls. Nothing more.

I wrote this:

```
#!/bin/bash

url="https://example.com"
for i in $(cat /home/warm_script/urls.txt); do
content="$(curl -m '20' -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36 (m__warmer)' "$url/$i")"
echo "$content" >> /home/warm_script/output.txt
done
```

It works but it give me the whole page content. I used the output.txt just to see the results. If it workings. I don't really want to take the whole page source

I will use this script to warm a page cache

What I do wrong please?

Comment: What exactly do you want in the `output.txt` file if not the content? The status code? You can throw away the content using `-o /dev/null`.

Comment: I don't really need something in the output.txt. Now you are saying I could get the status code there yes.

Comment: What about using `curl -o /dev/null ... 2>>/home/warm_script/output.txt`? This should throw away the content and save status information there.

Comment: Or just add the `-I` flag to `curl`

Comment: You mean: `"$(curl -o /dev/null -m '20' -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36 (m__warmer)' "$url/$i")" 2> /home/warm_script/output.txt`

Comment: No, without saving it to the variable: `curl -m '20' -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36 (m__warmer)' "$url/$i" -o /dev/null 2>>/home/warm_script/output.txt`

Comment: Ok.Understand. Trying that now.....Thank you. I will post so you right the answer!

Comment: Can't make it work....

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It is not getting the urls from the txt file with the answer you gave. Trying

Comment: And you got them before?

Comment: Yes. Fixed...it is working....I put accidentally an extra `/`. If I put this in cron will be fine, right?

Comment: If you configure cron correctly, yes

Comment: @dan1st Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `curl` not to output the content with `-o /dev/null` and forward the progress information to a file using `2>>/home/warm_script/output.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash

url="https://example.com"
for i in $(cat /home/warm_script/urls.txt); do
curl -m '20' -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36 (m__warmer)' "$url/$i" -o /dev/null /home/warm_script/output.txt
done
```

You can also use the `-I` option to just print headers:

```
content="$(curl -m '20' -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36 (m__warmer)' "$url/$i" -I)"
```

If you just want the status code, you can use `-o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s` (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1176569/1079262):

```
content="$(curl -m '20' -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36 (m__warmer)' "$url/$i" -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s)"
```

Answer (score 2):

As a simplified use case, try this:

```
outputFile="/home/warm_script/output.txt"
url="http://example.com"
if curl -m '20' -o /dev/null --fail --silent $url; 
then 
    echo "Success $url" >> "${outputFile}"
else 
    echo "Failed $url" >> "${outputFile}"
fi
```

Your output from the loop would look something like:

```
Success http://example.com/a.html
Success http://example.com/b.html
Failed http://example.com/c.html
Success http://example.com/d.html
```